# JavaScript On First Visit Agree to ToS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dialog

I am trying to make a script that if you've never visited the site before, it will redirect to /agree.htm where if they click okay it wont ask again, but if they don't click it will keep redirecting to the /agree.htm page.
Here's the JavaScript so far:

```
function doit() {
    document.getElementById('uuid').innerHTML = generateUUID();
    var yes = getUrlVars()["agreed"];
    if (yes == "true") {setCookie('VisitDate',1,365);   } 
    if (yes != "true")  {window.location = "/agree.htm";}
}
function getUrlVars() {
var vars = {};
var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
vars[key] = value;
});
return vars;
}
function getCookie(NameOfCookie){
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {              
    begin = document.cookie.indexOf(NameOfCookie+"=");       
    if (begin != -1) {           
      begin += NameOfCookie.length+1;       
      end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
      if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(begin, end));
    } 
  }
  return null;
}

function setCookie(NameOfCookie, value, expiredays) {
var ExpireDate = new Date();
ExpireDate.setTime(ExpireDate.getTime() + (expiredays * 24 * 3600 * 1000));

  document.cookie = NameOfCookie + "=" + escape(value) + 
  ((expiredays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + ExpireDate.toGMTString());
}

function delCookie (NameOfCookie) {
  if (getCookie(NameOfCookie)) {
    document.cookie = NameOfCookie + "=" +
    "; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT";
  }
}

function DoTheCookieStuff(LastChangeDate)
{
dt=new Date();
year=dt.getYear(); if (year<=9) {year="0"+year};
month=dt.getMonth()+1; if (month<=9) {month="0"+month};
date=dt.getDate(); if (date<=9) {date="0"+date};
ThisDate=year+month+date;

LastVisitDate=getCookie('VisitDate');
if (LastVisitDate!=null) 
 {  if (LastVisitDate<LastChangeDate) {}
    else {}
    setCookie('VisitDate',ThisDate,365)
 }

else {window.location  = "\agree.htm";}
}
```

It sets the cookie but will keep redirecting to the /agree.htm page.

AGREE.HTM:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>StratHaxxs Co. ToS Agreement</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
  .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.ui-widget.success-dialog {
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: .8em;
}

.ui-widget-content.success-dialog {
    background: #F9F9F9;
    border: 1px solid #90d93f;
    color: #222222;
}

.ui-dialog.success-dialog {
    left: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 0 !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.ui-dialog.success-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0;
}

.ui-dialog.success-dialog .ui-widget-header {
    background: #b0de78;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.ui-dialog.success-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    padding: 0.1em .5em;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane { 
    text-align: center;

}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset { 
    float: none;

}
</style>

  <script>
  $(function() {
  $('#success').dialog({
    height: 180,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    dialogClass: 'no-close success-dialog',
    buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          window.location.href = "/?agreed=true";
        }
      }
});
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="success"  title="Welcome!">
  <p>
  This is the first time you have visited our site, to continue to the site:
     Click 'Ok' if you agree to our <b>ToS</b>: <a href="/tos.html">Here</a><br><br>Otherwise press the back button or close this window. 
  </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Working Demo](http://wordpress.adriancarriger.com/so-examples/33978561/agree.htm)

It looks like you had all the right functions listed in your Javascript, but they weren't being called.

On page load you want to check if the cookie is present. If not, then you'll want to show the [jQuery Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) modal.

I added a button to remove the cookie so you can test.

Remove the Javascript from your `<script>` tag and replace it with this:

### Javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#remove-cookie').click(function() {
        delCookie('agreeCookie');
        $('h1').text('Cookie Removed');
        $('#remove-cookie').hide();
    });
    var cookieStatus = getCookie('agreeCookie');
    console.log(cookieStatus);
    if (cookieStatus != 'true') {
        tryRedirect('agree.htm');
        $('#success').show().dialog({
            height: 180,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            dialogClass: 'no-close success-dialog',
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    setCookie('agreeCookie', true, 100);
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    window.location.href = "index.html?agreed=true";
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        tryRedirect('index.html');
        $('#remove-cookie').show();
    }
    function tryRedirect(target) {
        var url = window.location.pathname;
        var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        if (filename != target) {
            window.location.href = target;
        }
    }
});
```

### To Test

1. Open the [Demo](http://wordpress.adriancarriger.com/so-examples/33978561/agree.htm) and click Ok in the dialog (this will add the cookie).
2. Reload the page. The cookie should be present and you'll be redirected to index.html and shown the Remove cookie button (repeat this step as much as you want and it should still do this).
3. Press the Remove cookie button and reload again. Now it should redirect to agree.htm and show the dialog again.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is: index.html AND agree.htm. The code for the index is first on my post where the second is agree.htm. Sorry for the mix up, can you please maybe fix this? :)

Comment: Okay, it should work now. I created a multi paged demo. Let me know if you have any questions.